# Validar checkbox cuando campo de texto tenga un valor

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito validar un checkbox solo cuando tengan escrita la dirección en el campo de texto, tengo los 2 checkbox y los 2 campos de texto dentro de un fieldset, como podria realizar esta validadion?

```
<fieldset class="cajas">
        <legend>Modo de envio</legend><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Modo" id="agencia" onclick="uncheck()" value="Agencia">Agencia<br>
        <label for="agen"></label>
        
        <input class="centrar" name="Agencia" id="agen" placeholder="Ejemplo: Agencia Starken bilbao">
        <br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="Modo" id="domicilio" onclick="uncheck()" value="Domicilio">Domicilio<br>
        
        <label for="direccion"></label>
        <input class="centrar" name="Direccion" id="Nombre" placeholder="Ejemplo: pasaje las tarkas 8554">
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: Puedes agregar el codigo JS de lo que hace `uncheck()`? A que te refieres con 'validar un checkbox'? desactivarlo si no hay texto?

Comment: asi es que se desactive si no hay texto, en el uncheck tengo una funcion que seleccione uno de los 2 checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Puedes monitorear los cambios en el contenido para desactivar el respectivo checkbox. En el ejemplo usé el evento `onkeyup` que ocurre cada ez que el usuario envia alguna entrada desde el teclado.

```js
function enableCheckbox(input, checkboxId){
  // console.log(input.value, checkboxId);
  document.getElementById(checkboxId).disabled=(input.value=='')
}


(function(){
    enableCheckbox(document.getElementById('agen'),'agencia');
    enableCheckbox(document.getElementById('Nombre'),'domicilio');    
})();
```

```html
<fieldset class="cajas">
        <legend>Modo de envio</legend><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Modo" id="agencia"  onclick="uncheck()" value="Agencia">Agencia<br>
        <label for="agen"></label>
        
        <input class="centrar" name="Agencia" id="agen"  onkeyup="enableCheckbox(this,'agencia')" placeholder="Ejemplo: Agencia Starken bilbao">
        <br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="Modo" id="domicilio"  onclick="uncheck()" value="Domicilio">Domicilio<br>
        
        <label for="direccion"></label>
        <input class="centrar" name="Direccion" id="Nombre"  onkeyup="enableCheckbox(this,'domicilio')" placeholder="Ejemplo: pasaje las tarkas 8554">
    </fieldset>
```

Par el caso contrario es similar:

```js
function uncheck(input, textId){
  // console.log(input.value, checkboxId);
  document.getElementById(textId).disabled=(!input.checked)
}


(function(){
    uncheck(document.getElementById('agencia'),'agen');
    uncheck(document.getElementById('domicilio'),'Nombre');    
})();
```

```html
<fieldset class="cajas">
        <legend>Modo de envio</legend><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Modo" id="agencia"  onclick="uncheck(this,'agen')" value="Agencia">Agencia<br>
        <label for="agen"></label>
        
        <input class="centrar" name="Agencia" id="agen"   placeholder="Ejemplo: Agencia Starken bilbao">
        <br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="Modo" id="domicilio"  onclick="uncheck(this,'Nombre')" value="Domicilio">Domicilio<br>
        
        <label for="direccion"></label>
        <input class="centrar" name="Direccion" id="Nombre"   placeholder="Ejemplo: pasaje las tarkas 8554">
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, pero si quiero que sea al reves, que al seleccionar el checkbox se habilite el campo de texto.

Comment: Hola @Daxtrox, agregué un ejemplo para el caso contrario.